# What is the easiest/best solution for generating Java client code from WADL?

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, wadl

I'm trying to generate a Java client to talk to my Glassfish application server. This server provides a WADL at `http://localhost:4848/management/application.wadl`.

I would like to generate that Java client code during a maven build, so I naturally took the [wadl-maven-plugin](http://wadl.java.net/wadl2java.html) route. unfortunatly, regarding the application.wadl file, that plugin generates a **48 MB** long Java source file, that seems to literally freeze Eclipse.

So, what are other good/efficient solutions to generate Java client out of WADL file ?

Comment: Why does it freeze Eclipse, cause it's generated code so you don't need to look into that code. It should be located in the target folder so no need to look at..

Comment: @khmarbaise for sure, however, there are many errors in that generated code (that's why I want to change used generator) that pushed me into taking a look at it.

Comment: My approach is to generate on command line take a look into the error messages and change the configuration or use a different generator but i never take a look into the generated code only if the generation is error free.

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, that's what I tend to do also (in maven context, to allow compilation pipeline to run with ease), but in that case the generation is not error free

Comment: Can you share your application.wadl file? Or maybe file it as a bug/rfe to wadl.java.net project.

Comment: @PavelBucek Like I said, it's the WADL generated by Glassfish. You can find one for Glassfish 3.1.1 here : https://gist.github.com/2658258

Comment: ok, missed that, sorry. Question here is - what are you trying to achieve? If I'm not mistaken, Glassfish Management Application do change in time / at least some parts are generated on the fly, like for example management of newly deployed application.

Comment: @PavelBucek Well, I was trying to create a kind of domain versionning mechanism (as an example adding a JMS queue through a REST call), but indeed it may not work well, due to the generated parts.